# How to find longest subsequence based on conditions in Impala SQL

Tags: sql, impala, subsequence

I have a SQL table on Impala that contains `ID`, `dt` (monthly basis with no skipped month), and `status` of each person ID. I want to check how long that each ID is in each status (my expected answer is shown on `expected` column)

I tried to solve this problem on the `value` column by using

```
count(status) over (partition by ID, status order by dt)
```

but it doesn't reset the `value` when the `status` is changed.

```
+------+------------+--------+-------+----------+
|  ID  |     dt     | status | value | expected |
+------+------------+--------+-------+----------+
| 0001 | 01/01/2020 |      0 |     1 |        1 |
| 0001 | 01/02/2020 |      0 |     2 |        2 |
| 0001 | 01/03/2020 |      1 |     1 |        1 |
| 0001 | 01/04/2020 |      1 |     2 |        2 |
| 0001 | 01/05/2020 |      1 |     3 |        3 |
| 0001 | 01/06/2020 |      0 |     3 |        1 |
| 0001 | 01/07/2020 |      1 |     4 |        1 |
| 0001 | 01/08/2020 |      1 |     5 |        2 |
+------+------------+--------+-------+----------+
```

Is there anyway to reset the counter when the `status` is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you partition by `ID` and `status`, two groups are formed for the values `0` and `1` in `status` field. So, the months `1, 2, 6` go into *first* group with `0` status and the months `3, 4, 5, 7, 8` go into the *second* group with `1` status. Then, the count function counts the number of statuses individually in those groups. Thus the *first* group has counts from `1` to `3` and the *second* group has counts from `1` to `5`. This query so far doesn't account for the change in statuses rather just simply divide the record set as per different status values.

One approach would be to divide the records into different blocks where each status change starts a new block. The below query follows this approach and gives the expected result:

```
SELECT ID,dt,status,
    COUNT(status) OVER(PARTITION BY ID,block_number ORDER BY dt) as value 
FROM (
    SELECT ID,dt,status,
        SUM(change_in_status) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY dt) as block_number
    FROM(
        SELECT ID,dt,status,
            CASE WHEN 
                    status<>LAG(status) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY dt)
                    OR LAG(status) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY dt) IS NULL 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
            END as change_in_status 
        FROM statuses
    ) derive_status_changes
) derive_blocks;
```

Here is a [working example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gBB5YytzxczmSXetx1Fyjv/0) in DB Fiddle.